# pypi erro when try to install gcsfs in google composer(airflow)

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow, dask, pypi, google-cloud-composer

I use google composer-1.0.0-airflow-1.9.0. I used dask in one of my DAG and wanted to setup composer to use dask. One of the required package for this DAG is gcsfs. When I tried to install it via Web UI I got the below error:

Composer Backend timed out. Currently running tasks are [stage: CP_COMPOSER_AGENT_RUNNING description: "Composer Agent Running. Latest Agent Stage: stage: DEPLOYMENTS_UPDATED\n ." response_timestamp { seconds: 1540331648 nanos: 860000000 } ].

Updated:

The error is coming from this line of code when dask tries to read file from gcp bucket:dd.read_csv(bucket) 
log:

```
     [2018-10-24 22:25:12,729] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/bytes/core.py", line 350, in get_fs_token_paths
     [2018-10-24 22:25:12,733] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     fs, fs_token = get_fs(protocol, options)
     [2018-10-24 22:25:12,735] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/bytes/core.py", line 473, in get_fs
     [2018-10-24 22:25:12,740] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     "Need to install `gcsfs` library for Google Cloud Storage support\n"
     [2018-10-24 22:25:12,741] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/utils.py", line 94, in import_required
     [2018-10-24 22:25:12,748] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     raise RuntimeError(error_msg)
     [2018-10-24 22:25:12,751] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: RuntimeError: Need to install `gcsfs` library for Google Cloud Storage support
     [2018-10-24 22:25:12,756] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     conda install gcsfs -c conda-forge
     [2018-10-24 22:25:12,758] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     or
     [2018-10-24 22:25:12,762] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     pip install gcsfs
```

When tried to install gcsfs in google composer UI using pypi got below error:

```
 {
   insertId:  "17ks763f726w1i"  
   logName:  "projects/xxxxxxxxx/logs/airflow-worker"  
   receiveTimestamp:  "2018-10-25T15:42:24.935880717Z"  
   resource: {…}  
   severity:  "ERROR"  
    textPayload:  "Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/gcsfuse", line 7, in <module>
    from gcsfs.cli.gcsfuse import main
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
     packages/gcsfs/cli/gcsfuse.py", line 3, in <module>
       fuse import FUSE
     ImportError: No module named fuse
    "  
   timestamp:  "2018-10-25T15:41:53Z"  
    }
```

Comment: check out these forums:
[1]: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-composer-discuss/Jcrh8d2X3uU
[2]: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-composer-discuss/A1xU5eTL4fg

Comment: @xiaoxia Lin: so is it a bug of google composer??!

Comment: Yeah, none of that is helpful (and doesn't mention fuse either). You want the logs of the install task - e.g., is it running conda or pip?

Comment: updated with google composer log when installing gcsfs

Comment: has this issue resolved?

Comment: @Sugimiyanto suma  no

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your error mssage doesn't mean much to me.

gcsfs is pure python code, so it is very unlikely that anything is going wrong with installing it - as is done very commonly with pip or conda. The dependency libraries are a bunch of google ones, some of which may require compilation (I don't know), so I would suggest trying to find out from logs which one is stalling and taking it up with them. On the other hand, this kind of thing can often be a network/intermittent problem, so waiting may also fix things.

For the future, I recommend basing installations around conda, which never needs to compile anything and is generally better at dependency tracking.

Comment: do you know gcsfs dependancies?I found here some: https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fuse.html#requirements

Comment: Not those, you are not using FUSE, right? See instead https://github.com/dask/gcsfs/blob/master/requirements.txt

Comment: I dont import FUSE in my DAG. is it required by gcsfs?

Comment: No it isn't - the requirements link you posted are optional extras in the case you wish to use gcsfs with FUSE.

Comment: installed those listed in the link, didnt help though... I also installed conda, but the DAG error is still showing up the same

Comment: You will need to find the logs. Also, you should *use* conda, not just install it.

Comment: From log found that FUSE is required so installed fusepy but now getting this new error : should install gcsfuse too??

 textPayload:  "Usage: gcsfuse [OPTIONS] BUCKET MOUNT_POINT

Comment: FUSE (and fusepy) is not required unless you explicitly want to use it. You are apparently calling it to get that message - why? You need to give more detail about what you're doing...

Comment: updated the question. basically wanted to use dask to read a huge csv files in gcp bucket

Comment: how can I install gcsfs using conda on google composer?

Comment: I have no idea how google composer works. These steps work for general linux environment: `  > wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
  > bash miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
  > export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
  > conda config --set always_yes yes --set changeps1 no
  > conda create -n test -c conda-forge dask gcsfs
  > source activate test

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the fact that Composer and Airflow have silent dependencies and they are not syncd. So if `gcsfs` installation has conflicts with Airflow dependency, we get this error. More details [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117666270). The only workarounds ( other than updating to the Nov 28 release of composer) are:

[Source](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117666270): Thanks to Jake Biesinger (jake.biesinger@infusionsoft.com)

> use a separate Kubernetes Pod for running various jobs, but it's a
>   large change and requires infra we're not very familiar with (GKE).
>   This particular issue can also be solved by installing dbt in a
>   PythonVirtualEnvOperator, then having the python_callable re-use the
>   virtualenv's bin dir, something like:
>
> ``` def _run_cmd_in_virtual_env(cmd):
>   subprocess.check_call(os.path.join(os.path.split(sys.argv[0])[0], cmd)
>
> task =
>   PythonVirtualEnvOperator(python_callable=_run_cmd_in_virtual_env,
>   op_args=('dbt',))  # this will call the temporarily-installed dbt
>   binary, something like `/tmp/virtualenv-asdasd/bin/dbt`.

```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but this might help you out.
In general, installing arbitrary system packages (like `fuse` or whatever which becomes the dependencies of what you are trying to install) is not supported by Google Composer. As discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!searchin/cloud-composer-discuss/sugimiyanto%7Csort:date/cloud-composer-discuss/jpxAGCPFkZo/mCx_P1LPCQAJ

However, you may be able to do this by uploading the package folder that you have installed it in your local (i.e. fuse), into your Google Cloud Storage bucket for example: `gs://<your_bukcet_name>/libs`, so that it becomes shared libraries.
Then, you can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in Google Composer to `/home/airflow/gcs/libs`, to make GCC look for shared libraries in that directory.

Then, try to reinstall the `gcsfs` using pypi Google Composer.